# how to use the data from factory in the same controller but in different file in angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying route from `home.html` to `profile.html` .I have data in script.js which i have written in factory.when profile button is clicked, the page is routing to profile.html,but the profile.js which is written in profile.html is not executing.I have same app in profile.html and profile.js.where am i doing wrong?

### home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <!-- define angular app -->
    <html ng-app="app">

   <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/profile"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>

<div id="main">

 <div ng-view></div>

</div>


</body>
```

### script.js

```
    // create the module and name it app
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
app.factory("Data", function(){
return  {profileName: "Hello Lucifer"};
});
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

app.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});
```

### profile.html(path:~/pages/profile.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="app" ng-controller="aboutController">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
            <script src="about.js"></script>
  </head>

 <div class="jumbotron text-center">

   <span>About Page</span>

   <p>{{ message }}</p>
      {{ results.name}}
  </div>
```

### profile.js(path:pages/profile.js)

```
 var app = angular.module('app');
   app.controller('aboutController',['$scope', '$http',function($scope,$http,Data) {
alert("sa");
    //data from api
    $scope.results = Data.profileName;
});
```

Comment: if you inject the factory on your module it will be exposed if you annotate it as a dependency in your controller

Comment: but any ways the script is not at all executing. i dont see any alert

Comment: You are missing it to inject `app.controller('aboutController',['$scope', '$http', 'Data',function($scope,$http,Data) {`

Comment: changed.but the profile.js is not at all getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

I did not included profile.js in home.html